# Unix shell - search Tab delimted file

Tags: shell, unix

Hi I have a tab delimited text file. The columns are age and name.
Number of rows are 50.

I want to find and output to a new file, the rows, when they age is "eighteen"

```
cat old_filename | grep "eighteen" > new_filename
```

when I try , it does not output the rows into the newfile but only the first instance it finds `eighteen`

Comment: You can provide a sample of your actual input file and an expected output to see if other tools can be suggested!

Comment: if it is really true that "it does not output the rows into the newfile but only the first instance" then there is something wrong with your system. Also, solution below is essentially the same thing (without unneeded `cat`). so does that work any better? If not, then try this on another machine. Also, to speed  up testing, I would just do `grep eighteen old_file` . Ah, was your `old_file` created on MS windows? if so, `dos2unix old_file` before running `grep`  may solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

grep can check inside files, it matches lines by default.

So if the input was:

```
name    age
tom     eighteen
joe     sixteen
sam     eighteen

grep "eighteen" old_filename  > new_filename
```

new_filename would have

```
tom     eighteen
sam     eighteen
```